# Google(.com) stops loading sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, windows-vista, browser, connection

I've got a problem - google.com stops loading sometimes.

I'm mostly using Chrome on Windows Vista. When this problem appears, I still can access it in other domains (say, google.ru or google.nl); accessing google.com in Chrome's anonymous mode also works. Some things (like openID authentification or search in Chrome) are tied to google.com, though, so it's still annoying.

Subdomains (like mail.google.com) can be accessed, while pages within domain (like google.com/calendar) cannot.

Ping and tracert show that the server is accessible. Trying to get to google.com in Firefox works sometimes, but not 100% of the time.

The problem can disappear by itself after some time (like a few hours). Closing and reopening browser also helps, so I guess it's something browser-related. Any ideas?

I have just had this problem, so I reloaded Chrome (needed Google's openID to log in to SU) and now it's gone. It's not regular, though - sometimes it doesn't appear for days, and I couldn't find any reason for that so far.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing chrome?

Comment: No. Will keep it in mind if no other way shows up. Thanks for advice!

Comment: But I sometimes experience this problem in Firefox as well, so it's beyond just Chrome.

Comment: Does it happen across all user profiles?

Comment: This seems like a simple DNS problem. Check that your hosts file is clean, and find out if your DNS cache needs updating (or even a change of DNS servers).

Comment: @RandolphWest, thanks! This makes sense indeed, as I sometimes get DNS error on other sites as well, but very infrequently, so it was not a problem. hosts file (at c:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts ) only contains two lines for localhost. Regarding the second part of your comment - I found how to forcefully flush DNS cache; but can you give any advice on how to get the DNS server address that should be used? Or how can I diagnose the problem further - I can ask provider tech support about it, but I need something to show them, so far they weren't very helpful.

Comment: See if using the Google DNS or OpenDNS servers helps.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your problem? This might be useful to other users.

Comment: I recall I didn't back then, it just went away.

Answer (score -2):

Try [re-installing](http://www.ehow.com/how_6460094_reinstall-google-chrome.html) Google Chrome

Comment: It happens in FF as well.